# How to access body property using office interop of email with permissions

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop

While trying to access "Body" property of an email with some permissions office interop throws following error: The object does not support this method.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The object does not support this method.
```

Is there any way to access the email "Body" property of emails who have some permissions set on them?